# Returning Value from For Loops in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I am attempting to learn C and have purchased a book to demonstrate some key aspects of the language.  It was all well until I found many of the examples did not function properly.  My IDE(Xcode) did not show any syntax errors so I do not understand why the following code will not work.

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
    /* count characters in input; 2nd version */
    int main() { 
    double nc; 
    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; + + nc) 
        ; 
    printf("%. 0f\ n", nc); }
```

This is the exact code from the book but it does not do anything.  Can someone please tell me how I can make this code work.  Thanks.

Comment: `+ + nc` --> `++nc`,  `"%. 0f\ n"` --> `"%.0f\n"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the extra spaces in your program. In the condition you are checking the char with `EOF`. We can find the `EOF` in the end of the files. If you want to enter it manually you want to press Cntrl+D. At that time your condition will fail and the count will display. It will not work completely if you use Cntrl+z or anything.

Answer (score 4):

Remove extra empty spaces.

Try the following.

```
   #include <stdio.h> 
    /* count characters in input; 2nd version */
    int main() { 
    double nc; 
    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc) 
        ; 
    printf("%.0f\n", nc); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; + + nc) 
    ;                            ^This space is not required operator is `++` wthout space.
 printf("%. 0f\ n", nc);
           ^This also is creating problem (extra space) %.0f will do
```